# SQLSVR and specifying instance name

Tags: php, sql-server

I am using PHP 5.5 and using SQLSVR to connect to MSSQL 2008R2.
As per documentation:

```
$server   = servername;
$database = somedatabase;
$username = someuser;
$password = somepassword;

$connInfo = array("Database"=>$database, "UID"=>$username, "PWD"=>$password);
$connTest = sqlsrv_connect( $server, $connInfo);
```

The above works with no problem.

The problem I am having is when I need to specify the instance name.

```
$server   = servername\instancename;
$database = somedatabase;
$username = someuser;
$password = somepassword;

$connInfo = array("Database"=>$database, "UID"=>$username, "PWD"=>$password);
$connTest = sqlsrv_connect( $server, $connInfo);
```

The above code works but it seems the instance name is not taken into consideration. By this, I mean that **ALL** the following seem to work and connect to **servername\instancename**.

```
$server   = servername\instancename;
$server   = servername\instancenam;
$server   = servername\instancena;
$server   = servername\instancen;
$server   = servername\inst;
```

Why does this happen? Surely each of the above would/should be considered as different instance name. I need to explicitly dictate the instance name and test connection to that server\instance.

Even when I do not specify the instance name I can connect to servername\instancename.

Thank you in advance!

**EDIT**
More information about this
I have form with 4 inputs and a test connection button

```
<input type="text" id="EditSiteServer" name="EditSiteServer" value="Server\Instance" required>
<input type="text" id="EditSitePort" name="EditSitePort" value="1433" required>
<input type="text" id="EditSiteUsername" name="EditSiteUsername" value="Username" required>
<input type="text" id="EditSitePassword" name="EditSitePassword" value="Passwrod" required>
<button class="btn" type="button" name="connTest" id="btnconnTest" onclick="TestConnection()">Test Connection</button>
```

When a user clicks the "Test Connection" button is fires this javascript/jquery function

```
function TestConnection(){
    $("body").css("cursor", "progress");
    var processing = "<button class=\"btn btn-lg btn-default btn-block disabled\" type=\"button\">...checking...</button>"
    $("#testConn").html(processing);
    var s = document.forms["createSiteForm"]["InputSiteServer"].value + ", "+document.forms["createSiteForm"]["InputSitePort"].value;
    var un = document.forms["createSiteForm"]["InputSiteUsername"].value;
    var pw = document.forms["createSiteForm"]["InputSitePassword"].value;
    var db = document.forms["createSiteForm"]["InputSiteDatabase"].value;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../process/sites/check_connection.php",
        dataType:"html",
        data: { server : s, database : db, username : un, password : pw }
    }).done(function(data){
        $("#testConn").html(data);  
        $("body").css("cursor", "default");
    });
}
```

This then post to check_connection.php

```
<?php
$server   = $_POST['server'];
$database = $_POST['database'];
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
//echo $server." ".$database." ".$username." ".$password."<br>";
$connInfo     = array("Database"=>$database, "UID"=>$username, "PWD"=>$password);
$connTest = sqlsrv_connect($server, $connInfo);
if( $connTest ) {
    echo "Connection succeeded";
} else {
    echo "Connection failed";
}
?>
```

From further testing, anything right of '\' in EditSiteServer can be anything as stated above and the connection will succeed. I need to explicitly stated the instance name.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: No idea, I tried on my machine, one letter change and I get error.... just ot be sure, same file you editing the instancename?

Comment: @MarkNg Do you have multiple instances on your server?